RJ-45 port works for one device but not the others
I've got a really strange ethernet connection issue that I'm hoping someone can help me with.
My modem is located in a storage room where there's a RJ-45 jack on the wall. One of the ethernet ports of the modem connected to this jack. There's also another RJ-45 jack on the living room wall, which I know connected to the storage room jack. Here's the mystery: when I connect devices to the RJ-45 port in the living room:

Two different PCs: Neither works ❌
Two different switches: Neither works ❌
USB-C hub with an Ethernet port: Doesn't work ❌
Smart TV: Works ✅

When I say "doesn't work," I mean that even the ethernet port light doesn't turn on with PCs, switches.
When I use a long Ethernet cable directly from the storage room to the living room, everything works perfectly. But, as you can imagine, I don’t want a cable running through my home.
The only thing that comes to mind is buying an network cable tester to see if there is a signal issue, but I don’t want to waste money on something I'll use just once, especially when I'm not even sure if it will help.
Has anyone experienced anything like this before or have any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Check wall-jack wiring -- it's likely wired wrong. If there's enough slack, snip both ends and put on new RJ-45 plugs correctly. The TV is more accommodating to switched wires. See https://serverfault.com/questions/953891/ethernet-cable-only-works-a-to-b-not-reversed-why
